# Asking about responsiveness?

Tags: html, css

I have a school project to make a website
I've made most of it but i don't know how to make everything responsive cus our teacher said we can't use bootstrap and we only had 1 lesson about it which I unfortunetly wasn't present

I have main site and 8 subpages they all have the same structure so if I'll know how to style 1 it'll be easy to do the rest. There's some text in polish so don't bother they're just informations from wiki.

That's my main site:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Poznaj Dinozaury </title>
    <meta name="description" content="Serwis poświęcony dinozaurom Naucz się wszystkiego, co chcesz wiedzieć o tych potężnych jaszczurach!" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="dinozaury, dino" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Black+Ops+One|Caveat+Brush|Montserrat" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link href="css/fontello.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">

        <div id="logo">
            Poznaj Dinozaury 
        </div>

        <div id="menu">
            <div class="option"> <a href="index.html" title="Strona Główna">Strona Główna</a><br></div>
            <div class="option"> <a href="1.html" title="Etymologia">Etymologia</a><br></div>
            <div class="option"> <a href="2.html" title="Definicja filmogenetyczna">Definicja filmogenetyczna</a><br></div>
            <div class="option"> <a href="3.html" title="Biologia">Biologia</a><br></div>
            <div class="option"> <a href="4.html" title="Wymarcie">Powstanie ptaków</a><br></div>
            <div class="option"> <a href="5.html" title="Bibliografia">Wymarcie</a><br></div>
            <div class="option"> <a href="6.html" title="Powstanie ptaków">Historia badań</a><br></div>
            <div class="option"> <a href="7.html" title="Historia badań">Kontakt</a><br></div><br>


            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="topbar">
            <div id="topbarL">
                M
            </div>
            <div id="topbarR">
                <span class="bigtitle2">O projekcie słów kilka</span>
                <div style="height: 15px;"></div>
                Projekt zrobiony od zera przez Marcina Galosa z 3b-1 jako projekt z Witryn i aplikacji internetwych do końca kwietnia 2019r.
                <br><br>
                Wszelkie informacje pochodzą z <a href="https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinozaury" title="Wikipediia">Wikipedii</a>.


            </div>
            <div id="dino">



            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="sidebar">

                <div class="Galeria"> <a href="8.html" title="Strona Główna">Galeria</a><br></div>

                <br><br>


            <div class="socials">
                <div class="socialdivs">
                    <div class="fb">
                        <i class="icon-facebook"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="yt">
                        <i class="icon-youtube"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tw">
                        <i class="icon-twitter"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="gplus">
                        <i class="icon-gplus"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear:both"></div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <span class="bigtitle">Dinozaury</span>

            <div class="dottedline"></div>



            <p> (Dinosauria) – zróżnicowany klad zauropsydów. Pojawiły się w triasie, około 237 milionów lat temu. Stanowiły dominującą grupę kręgowców lądowych od początku jury (około 201 milionów lat temu) przez 135 milionów lat, do końca kredy (66 milionów lat temu), kiedy wymieranie kredowe (wyznaczające granicę kreda-trzeciorzęd i koniec mezozoiku) doprowadziło do zniknięcia większości linii. Zapis kopalny wskazuje, że w jurze ptaki wyewoluowały z dinozaurów zaliczanych do teropodów, wobec czego przez literaturę przedmiotu wydaną w XXI wieku uznawane są za grupę dinozaurów. Przeżywając katastrofę sprzed 66 milionów lat, dzięki swym potomkom stały się kontynuatorami linii dinozaurów po czasy współczesne.
                    <br><br>
                Do ostatnich dziesięcioleci XX wieku wszystkie grupy dinozaurów uznawano za wymarłe. Jednakże zapis kopalny wskazuje, że ptaki, nazywane dziś w języku angielskim avian dinosaurs („ptasie dinozaury”), są współczesnymi potomkami opierzonych dinozaurów. Wyewoluowały one ze swych teropodzich przodków w okresie jury. Wobec tego ptaki stanowią jedyną linię dinozaurów, która przetrwała zagładę.
                    <br><br>
                Wobec powyższego do dinozaurów zalicza się również ptaki. Z kolei dinozaury nie będące ptakami określa się mianem non-avian dinosaurs, tłumaczonym na język polski jako „nieptasie dinozaury”, pojawia się też określenie „nieptasie teropody”.
                    <br><br>
                Dinozaury to z taksonomicznego, morfologicznego i ekologicznego punktu widzenia zróżnicowana grupa zwierząt. Do ptaków zaliczanych jest obecnie ponad 10 000 gatunków, co czyni je najbardziej zróżnicowaną grupą kręgowców z wyjątkiem okoniokształtnych. Dzięki dowodom kopalnym do 2006 paleontolodzy wyróżnili ponad 500 rodzajów i ponad tysiąc gatunków nieptasich dinozaurów, podczas gdy w 2014 liczba opisanych rodzajów wynosiła 943. Dinozaury zamieszkiwały wszystkie kontynenty – na wszystkich bowiem znajdowane są ich szczątki kopalne, jak i występują współczesne gatunki. Zaliczają się do nich zarówno roślinożercy, jak i mięsożercy. Pierwotnie cechowała je dwunożność, ale wiele wymarłych grup obejmowało formy czworonożne, a także poruszające się zarówno na dwóch, jak i na czterech łapach. Liczne grupy wykształciły wyszukane struktury, jak rogi czy kryzy. Niektóre taksony wymarłe wykształcały także takie modyfikacje szkieletu, jak kolce czy pancerz. Potwierdzono składanie jaj i budowę gniazd u wszystkich grup. O ile dzisiejsze ptaki osiągają zazwyczaj niewielkie rozmiary, co wiąże się z umiejętnością lotu, formy prehistoryczne osiągały często duże rozmiary. Największe zauropody mogły osiągać nawet 58 m długości przy wysokości 9,25 m. Wizja nieptasich dinozaurów jako jednorodnie gigantycznych jest jednak nieprawdziwa, wynika z większej tendencji do zachowywania się dużych kości. Wiele nieptasich dinozaurów było niewielkich rozmiarów, jak mierzący około 50 cm długości Xixianykus.
                    <br><br>
                Nazwa dinozaury oznacza „straszne jaszczurki”, dlatego też może wprowadzać w błąd – dinozaury nie były jaszczurkami, ani nie były z nimi blisko spokrewnione. Reprezentują natomiast oddzielną grupę „gadów”, oprócz ptaków ich najbliższymi współczesnymi krewniakami są krokodyle. Jak wiele wymarłych form, nie wykazują one cech tradycyjnie uznawanych za „gadzie”, jak zmiennocieplność czy poruszanie się na kończynach odwiedzionych na boki. Co więcej, wiele grup prehistorycznych zwierząt, takich jak mozazaury, ichtiozaury, pterozaury, plezjozaury, a nawet Dimetrodon, popularnie uznawanych za dinozaury, w rzeczywistości nimi nie są. Przez pierwszą połowę XX wieku, zanim uznano ptaki za dinozaury, większość społeczności naukowej uznawała dinozaury za powolne i zmiennocieplne. Zmiana nastąpiła w latach 60. (odrodzenie dinozaurów). Stwierdzono, że wszystkie dinozaury, w tym mezozoiczne, prowadziły aktywny tryb życia i cechowały się szybkim metabolizmem, tak jak dzisiejsi ich przedstawiciele; wykazywały też liczne adaptacje umożliwiające interakcje społeczne.
                    <br><br>
                Odkąd naukowcy zaczęli badać i opisywać pierwsze skamieliny nieptasich dinozaurów w pierwszej połowie XIX wieku, zmontowane szkielety nieptasich dinozaurów stały się głównymi atrakcjami muzeów wielu krajów, a dinozaury stały się częścią kultury. Wielkie rozmiary niektórych grup, jak również niekiedy przerażająca i fantastyczna natura, zapewniły tym stworzeniom regularną obecność w bestsellerach książkowych i filmowych, jak Zaginiony świat Arthura Conan Doyle'a czy Park Jurajski Michaela Crichtona. Trwały entuzjazm opinii publicznej dla tych zwierząt doprowadził do znacznego wsparcia finansowego dla poświęconej im dziedziny nauki. Media regularnie donoszą o nowych odkryciach.</p> 
            <br /><br />



        </div>  



        <div id="footer">
            Poznaj Dinozaury&copy; Wszelkie prawa zastrzeżone
        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"> </script>





</body>
</html>
```

And that's my css to it:

```
body
{
    font-family: 'Black Ops One', cursive;
    background-image: url(img/gray.png);

    /* Background pattern from Toptal Subtle Patterns */
}

#container
{
    width: 1300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: left;
}

#logo
{
    color: #f4d941;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 44px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: 900;
    width: 100%;
}

#menu
{
    font-size:15px;
    background-color: #303030;
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: #f4d941;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

#topbar
{
    background-color: #f4d941;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    height: 170px;
    width: 100%;
}

#topbarL
{
    font-size: 110px;
    float:left;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 138px;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 2px dotted #303030;
}

#topbarR
{
    color: #56564e;
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 760px;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: justify;
}


#sidebar
{
    float: left;
    width: 148px;
    min-height: 680px;
    padding:20px;
    background-color: #303030;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: fixed;
}

#content
{
    background-image: url(img/d.png),url(img/gravel.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat,repeat;
    position: relative;
    left: 16%;

    float: left;
    padding: 40px;
    width: 1030px;
    background-color: #dedede;
    min-height: 1108px;
    text-align: justify;
    border-left: 2px dotted #f4d941;
}

#footer
{
    clear: both;
    color: #f4d941;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.Galeria
{
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 50px;
    height: 25px;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-right: 2px 
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.Galeria:hover
{
    background-color: #f4d941;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.option
{
    float: left;
    min-width: 50px;
    height: 25px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-right: 2px 
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.option:hover
{
    background-color: #f4d941;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.optionL
{
    font-size:18px;
    height:25px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 2px dotted #444444;
}

.optionL:hover
{
    background-color: #f4d941;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bigtitle
{
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color: #f4d941;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px gray;
}

.bigtitle2
{
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color: #56564e;



}

.dottedline
{
    height: 5px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: 2px dotted #444444;
}



/*Unvisited link*/
a:link
{
    color: aliceblue;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-left: 2px solid #f4d941;
}

/*Visisted link*/
a:visited
{
    color: aliceblue;
    border-left: 2px solid #f4d941;
}

/*Hovered link*/
a:hover
{
    color: #56564e;
    border-left: 2px solid#444444;
}



.socials
{
    width:100%;
    height: 155px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #303030;
}

.socialdivs
{
    width: 150px;
    height: 155px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #303030;


}

.fb
{
    width: 150px;
    height: 155px;
    border-top: 2px solid #f4d941;


}

.fb:hover
{
    background-color: #4668b3;
}

.yt
{
    width: 150px;
    height: 155px;
    border-top: 2px solid #f4d941;

}

.yt:hover
{
    background-color: #d94348;
}

.tw
{
    width: 150px;
    height: 155px;
    border-top: 2px solid #f4d941;

}

.tw:hover
{
    background-color: #3095d3;
}

.gplus
{
    width: 150px;
    height: 155px;
    border-top: 2px solid #f4d941;

}

.gplus:hover
{
    background-color: #d95333;
}

/*Pictures*/

#b
{
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}

#b1
{
    width: 250px;
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
}

#b2
{
    width: 350px;
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
}

#b3
{
    width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
}

#b4
{
    width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
}

#b5
{
    width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
}

.gal
{
    float: left;
    width: 340px;
    padding: 1px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center; 
    text-shadow: #56564e;
    border-bottom: 2px dotted #444444;
}

.g
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out
}

.g:hover
{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.35)rotate(5deg);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.35)rotate(5deg);
    transform: scale(1.35)rotate(5deg);
}

p
{
    text-shadow: 2px 2px white;
}
```

How to make it responsive?

Comment: What you're asking is far too broad for a Stack Overflow question.  Generally the use of Bootstrap comes highly recommended, and if you can't use it for a purely academic exercise then that further stresses the idea that this is *your* academic exercise for your own learning purposes.  It sounds like you need to catch up on your course lessons and/or conduct some research on responsive web design.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55801854/alter-page-style-because-of-screen-inches/55802207#55802207

Comment: There are other ways to learn about responsive design, use Google and search for "responsive design tutorial". This question is too broad and show [no attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS you have given margin, padding, height, width as px values. They won't change when the screen size changes.

If you give those values in percentage, they will be changed according to the screen size.

That's the only way to make your website responsive without using bootstrap.

Example:
Lets say your screen's width is 2000px and you have a component with 200px now.
You can calculate the percentage and change the CSS.

change `width: 200px;` to `width: 10%;`

Comment: theres also media css you can use to render differently depending on screensize

Comment: Eh? No, Bootstrap and other CSS frameworks aren't magic. Fluid width layouts are often used as part of responsive layouts, but a major part of most responsive layouts is using CSS3 media queries to make style changes to adapt the page to different screen (viewport) sizes.